# .Net MVC : unable to get ViewBag value in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor

As a beginner i am doing very simple example to  understand  basic Razor concepts ,  When i set some values using ViewBag in my controller class and try to get them in view they are not printed , neither it shows insentience for this nor any error  , Please hep me with it .  this is what i  am doing

**Mode Class : Product**

```
public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId      { get; set; }
        public string Name        { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Decimal Price      { get; set; }
        public string Catagoery   { get; set; }
    }
```

**HomeController**  (pasting only specific method that is not working for me )

```
   public ActionResult MyProduct()

        {
            ViewBag.ProductCount = 1; 
            ViewBag.ProductQuality = "Good"; 
             return View(product); 

        }
```

**ProductView**

```
@model RazorApplication.Models.Product

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Demo";
    Layout = "~/Views/_BasicLayout.cshtml";
}

<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td><td>@Model.Name</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quality</td><td>@ViewBag.ProductCount</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Quality</td><td>@ViewBag.ProductQuality</td>

        </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: code lookes fine it should print Count of Porduct

Comment: if its fine shouldn't it show IntelliSense  when i try to get these  values in view ?

Comment: it will not show intellisense in ViewBag case, it value is determined on runtime its a dynamic property

Comment: the view you posted is returned from MyProduct action

Comment: yes and for that action i have registered view  product and that shows name of product properly  but  not Viewbag contents , this is strongly typed view and i renamed it while creating ,  is there anything wrong with it ?

Comment: yes  name is printing,  but ViewBag  values are not  printing .

Comment: try TempData["ProductCount"] =1 and same for ProductQuality

Comment: ok i cleared the cache  and its printing now ..

Comment: hmmm, means page was loading from browser's cache

Comment: yes that was the problem  maybe first time i did something wrong  and then it went on with that, thank u bro

Comment: i am writing the thing happened with you in answer so that it hepls if someone else also faces this type of issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine, you are setting values in `ViewBag` in action, they should be printed in the page, try **Ctrl + F5** to refresh your page, may be the page is loading from browser's cache,by pressing **Ctrl + F5** all the page will be rendered fresh from server.

Answer (score 3):

Does this code event compile? I ask because what you have generally works but there are errors in the code, with names etc. but I think that is the result from making a sample.

If you can get it to compile you should be fine. Putting your code into .NET Fiddle and things are running and printing out properly. http://dotnetfiddle.net/wgE30l

You are not getting the name from Model because it was never set. The ViewBag works independently from the model and displays properly.